# PL/pgSQL - How Can I Dynamically Set a Column Size in PostgresQL Using a Variable?

Tags: postgresql, variables, casting

I need to initialize a column in a temp table to contain string data from a source table. I want to set my temp table column to the size of the maximum value in the source data. I can set a variable to get the source column max data size like so, but get an error when trying to set the column size in my CAST() statement using the variable as the limit :

```
CREATE FUNCTION local_schema.my_func() RETURNS boolean AS $$
DECLARE 
  max_length_org_nm numeric := (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(org_nm)) FROM other_schema.tablename);
BEGIN
  CREATE TABLE local_schema.temp_table as 
  SELECT CAST('--' as character varying(max_length_org_nm)) as org_nm
  FROM other_schema.tablename;
...etc
```

This throws the error "ERROR:  invalid data type specification" from the line where the CAST() is called.

I am just sure I am being dense here, but cannot seem to find documentation on how to use a variable as a column size in a CAST statement. Is it wrong to choose "numeric" as the data type for my variable?  Am I referencing the variable improperly? Can anyone offer me a leg up on this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is a possible solution:

```
create function my_func() 
returns boolean
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
 max_length_org_nm numeric;
begin
 select max(length(org_nm)) into max_length_org_nm from mytable;
 execute format('CREATE TABLE temp_table AS
                 SELECT CAST(%L as character varying(%s)) as org_nm 
                 FROM mytable', '--', max_length_org_nm);
 return true;
end;
$$;
CREATE FUNCTION

select * from mytable;
 org_nm 
--------
 a
 ab
 abcdef
(3 rows)

select my_func();
 my_func 
---------
 t
(1 row)

\d temp_table

                   Table "public.temp_table"
 Column |         Type         | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 org_nm | character varying(6) |           |          |
```